# Do I need Installation or Session classes for mobile back end database?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, azure-mobile-services, azure-sql-database

In the past, I used Parse's MBaaS. With its decline, I'm learning to build my own back end for an iOS application with a number of tools, including an Azure SQL Database.

I noticed that in Parse, there are default classes for `Installation` and `Session`. The fields for these classes are listed below. It seems like some of this information could just be for analytics, but some necessary for push notifications and updates.

Are these classes mostly specific to how Parse did things, or are they essential for any iOS/mobile application? If so, which fields are necessary, and for what? If this question is overly broad and I just need to do some reading, what resources would you recommend? (If needed, I can provide more info on the fields - type, common values, etc.)

### `Installation`

- objectId
- GCMSenderId
- deviceToken
- localeIdentifier
- badge
- parseVersion
- ACL
- appIdentifier
- appName
- updatedAt
- deviceType
- channels
- pushType
- installationId
- appVersion
- timeZone
- createdAt

### `Session`

- objectId
- sessionToken
- expiresAt
- ACL
- user
- updatedAt
- createdWith
- installationId
- restricted
- createdAt

Comment: It would probably be better to describe the feature you are trying to implement -- Parse had lots of different use-cases -- if you need "literally everything parse could do", then maybe it's better to use their open-source implementation -- or Azure's Parse clone.

Comment: You can also run Parse on Azure (using a one of Azure's managed database services) and then you don't have to change your code at all. See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-welcomes-parse-developers/.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, have you thought about running Parse elsewhere?   Azure allows you to run Parse on their service so the SDK would be practically identical.  Review the [Parse Migration Guide](https://parse.com/migration) for more details of how to do this in your app and the [Azure Announcement](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-the-publication-of-parse-server-with-azure-managed-services/) for details of what Azure provides.

If you still want to go it alone, decide what you need to do and write for that.  Completely ignore Parse exists.  What do you need?  I suspect you need what pretty much all cloud connected apps require - authentication, data access and storage, push notifications.  I may be a little biased, but a great option for these is [Azure Mobile Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/learning-paths/appservice-mobileapps/).

Comment: I looked into a number of options besides Parse - AWS, Azure, and numerous other 3rd party services. There's the ever present question of whether I should outsource pieces of a project, or learn to build them myself. I may end up using higher level services on future projects, but I think it'd be at least helpful to get an idea of what's going on under the hood by giving it a shot myself this time around. Forgetting Parse exists is good advice. It's just hard learn all the ins and outs of what is really 'required', versus what's a matter of choice in how to implement things.